# Authenticate to a web server and download a file

Tags: powershell, curl, basic-authentication

I need help with authenticating to a web server to download a file.

To follow my example, use this newly created trail account, that contains no personal data:

```
https://www.finanzen.net/anmelden    
Username: jensleuscher@xmail.de (a dummy name)    
Passwort: 999Test%
```

Hover over the User icon at the top right and choose 'Musterdepots'.
This will load a list with one item 'Musterdepot'. In the corresponding line, hover over the download link on the right and note that the URL is:
https://www.finanzen.net/depot/depot_export_csv.asp?pkdepnr=19405034&intDepotTypId=1

Copy it using right mouse menu and paste it in a new browser tab. Now the file 'Finanzen.net-Musterdepot.csv' will be downloaded to your download directory.

**I want to download this file using a script, without the need to open a browser.**

I tried:

**cURL**:

```
curl -X GET "https://www.finanzen.net/depot/depot_export_csv.asp?pkdepnr=19405034&intDepotTypId=1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "DNT: 1" -H "Referer: https://www.finanzen.net/" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0"
```

**Powershell**:

```
$username = "jensleuscher@xmail.de"
$password = "999Test%"
$URL="https://www.finanzen.net/depot/depot_export_csv.asp?pkdepnr=19405034&intDepotTypId=1"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($password)"))
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -uri $URL -Headers @{'Accept'='text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8';'Authorization'=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
$response.content > test.html
```

The response will not contain the expected .csv file, but a web page to log in or to create a new account. I probably need to authenticate first before my request. But I have no idea how. Perhaps I need to set and send a cookie, or I need to establish a session, have a key or token or whatever.

There's no API and no documentation.

How can that be done?

Comment: What protocol are you going to use to download the file?  Do you have the permission to perform FTP.  Invoke-WebRequest is using HTTP protocol.  Does the server have a method using HTTP to perform a download?  A client can only perform actions that the server is programmed to perform.

Comment: you can press F12 to see ,what  are the requested used when performing download

Comment: @jdweng I gave the target URL of a link. It's HTTP(S), not ftp. An .asp file is called and passed parameters, so I guess the server will build the response on the fly, thus it is not a FTP-downloadable file.

Comment: A server does not "build on the fly".  It must be programmed with standard methods in the protocol , part of a library, or custom programmed.  Most servers have FTP protocol enabled.  What status are you getting in the response?

Comment: @jdweng You have so many badges and reputations, I won't explain that .asp files on ISS servers and .php files build the response on the fly, come on. They are dynamic, not static and you can't download the results. And neither their sources. There pages are scripts executed in the server, that receive optional parameters in the URL (like here), build their dynamic html response on the fly and send it in the response packets. There're no files to download. --- And no, ftp is not enabled.

Comment: There is program that create the dynamic results.  If the server is not programmed to perform a download, you cannot do the download.  You cannot create a dynamic download if the method is not programmed.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, you're right. But I think I didn't ask for that. The question was, how can I establish an authenticated session to this paticular web server and then sent an authenticated request from a script, just like the browser would. What form and parameters does my cURL need in order for the server to respond in a way it would respond if I clicked on the link on the web page, while being logged in.

Comment: You doing an HTTP request/response.  So your request must meet both the HTTP specification and meet the requirements of the server.  Every programming language (library) the messages that is sent between the client and server are the same.  A two step authentication the browser library will automatically do the two steps together, while a programming language you need to perform the two steps separately.  Browsers are smarter then most programming languages with authentication when one method fails will retry with a different authentication.  Also defaults headers may be different.

Comment: An HTTP Request contains a URI, HTTP Headers, and body no matter what programming language. The header UserAgent specifies which type browser is being used because not all browsers are the same.  The content type and content length must be consistent with the body.  Some libraries will automatically calculate the length and other the programmer must do the calculation.  Using a browser a token may get established and then using a programming language the code will work until the token expires.  Code looks like it works but will fail when token expires.  There is no one answer to your question.

Comment: @jdweng ok, thank you for this explanation. I can successfully query depot_export_csv.asp with other parameters that don't require to be authenticated, and receive unprotected files. I had to add the user agent string, but then it worked. So I guess in terms of protocols etc. everything is all right. Just when trying to access the files in my depot, I'll receive a page saying that I'm not authorized. So I need to authenticate in some way beforehand, and I don't know how to do it. That was my question. You might look into the example account and see me, if you can help me.

Comment: You link is trying to add an extension into Chrome so I can't get to link.  The authentication is using your username password to get a token.   You need to follow the website example.  Not sure if you need a base 64 string.